# Groovy XmlSlurper access attribute value in root node

Tags: xml, groovy, xml-parsing

I'm trying to accomplish accessing the attributes that are part of the root node using Groovy and XmlSlurper.  I can do this easily with nested nodes, but can't seem to access the root node.

Here is the XML structure (simplified):

```
<coverage lines-covered="2353" lines-valid="2943">
    <sources />
    <packages />
</coverage>
```

I'd like to be able to get to the lines-covered and lines-valid attribute values.  Here is the code I'm trying out:

```
def cobertura = new XmlSlurper().parse(xml)
def coverage = cobertura.coverage
def lines = cobertura.find { it.@lines-covered }
println lines
```

I've also tried:

```
def cobertura = new XmlSlurper().parse("cobertura-coverage.xml")
def coverage = cobertura.coverage
println coverage.@lines-covered
```

And:

```
def cobertura = new XmlSlurper().parse("cobertura-coverage.xml")
println cobertura.@lines-covered
```

Comment: `@lines-covered` will be parsed as `@lines - covered`; when properties have other chars you must quote them.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for fixing my silly parentheses/quotes error and the incorrect spelling (dear God, I have no idea how I let that happen...)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to put the `lines-covered` part in quotes since it contains a dash:

```
def cobertura = new XmlSlurper().parse("cobertura-coverage.xml")
println cobertura.@'lines-covered'
```

Comment: :) Don't you love the simple fixes? Please consider marking this as [the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it fixed your issue.